# Data transfer performance between ICS and Jelly Bean

Tags: android, performance, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have been working on my app which periodically needs to sync its data to the application server.I was initially working on ICS( 4.0.3) but later upgraded to Jelly Bean (4.1.2).I notice a considerable time difference for the data to sync to the server.

I feel ICS was faster than JB for synching the data.Has anyone felt so? If not,What else could be the reason for this sluggishness of data transfer when I upgraded to JB? Thanks !

Comment: Explain this: `I was initially working on ICS( 4.0.3) but later upgraded to Jelly Bean (4.1.2)`.

Comment: By that I mean I was testing my app on my device which had ICS(4.0.3) running on it.Later I happened to upgrade my device with JB(4.1.2).Upon testing the app with this latest OS on my device(4.1.2) I found that the communication of my app with the appln server was taking far more time than when I had ICS running before.So I am wondering if anyone has faced a similar issue with JB.